# Is it good idea to cascade SEPIC converters to extend the input voltage range of the XL6009?

Tags: circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, constant-current, sepic, switching-transients

I'm currently working on designing a current controlled SEPIC converter with a wider range of input voltage for a medium sized power application which can be powered by a lithium battery.

The existing cheap ICs I've come across have a narrow operating voltage range, like the infamous XL6009 with a typical Vin of 5V. There are smaller boost converters available that operate at much lower voltages, like MT3608 down to 2V.

My idea is to cascade these converters, where the small boost converter powers the XL6009 by stepping up the input voltage to supply the IC, but not the inductor.

There are current controlled XL6009 modules out there which somewhat looks like this:

[image]

This one is for the XL4015 but the idea is same.

My idea here is: Replace the 78l05 linear regulator with an MT3608 SEPIC converter to not only power the voltage reference and the jellbean op-amp but also the XL6009. The reason I want to power the XL6009 is because although it is specified in the datasheet as having an UVLO voltage of 3V, it never works correcty at these voltages, the output regulation gets out of control. Since I want to power it by a battery, the current specifications are unsuitable.

[image]

My question is: Can cascading boost converters in this manner effectively increase the dynamic input range? Are there any potential issues or complications that could arise from this arrangement? I understand that boost converter ICs function as switches and do not consume much power when turning on and off. Any insights, advice, or considerations would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The circuit must operate with an input voltage range of 2.5V to 24V and it needs to output approximately 2A @ 12V, which is roughly 20 watts.

Datasheets:

[XL6009](https://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/XL6009/XL6009-DC-DC-Converter-Datasheet.pdf)

[MT3608](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf)

Comment: I know there are good quality TI ICs with better characteristics, but they have a small footprint which is challenging for me to work on. I cannot source them in my country, and I don't have the budget for them in general. I understand that using four inductors may seem unreasonable, but it is feasible for me.

Comment: Why the complication of SEPIC converters? What input voltage range is required and, what output current is needed?

Comment: The accessibility and low price are the primary reasons for choosing the SEPIC topology. The required voltage range is 2.5V to 24V. Despite the existence of potentially superior topologies, would it still technically work?

Comment: SEPIC would naturally cost more than a standard boost converter circuit because it uses two inductors. You didn't state the output current needed. What output voltage is required?

Comment: It's my bad. Let's say the required output current is 2 amps, the output voltage is 12 volts, and the power requirement is approximately 24 watts.

Comment: Please add all these details to your question (including the output voltage). I mean I could assume it is 10 volts but power is usually "average power" unless otherwise stated.

Comment: I appreciate your guidance. I am a new user on this forum, and I would like to express my gratitude.